# Received Error Unable to load the requested class: File (XAMPP)

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I'm running XAMPP, just had to reinstall it, and when I'm running a codeigniter application, that worked before, I received Unable to load the requested class: File

Is there anything that I need to change in CI or XAMPP?

Comment: Is File a class within your application?

Answer (score 0):

replace your system folder with fresh one.. seems like you have dropped some files.